# After sonarqube upgrade 5.2 -> 5.6, WebServer is not operational any more

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver, sonarqube5.6

I'm using WindowsServer2008 and MySql 5.6.31. I wanted to upgrade
SonarQube from version 5.2 to 5.6. After starting SonarQube the
 log-file shows the below lines. Everything should be finde, except the WebServer doesn't become operational:
 **INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Waiting for Web Server to be operational...
 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...**

When I try to reach the WebServer in the browser, I get the message from ApacheTomcat:

```
 HTTP Status 404 - /sessions/new

type Status report

message /sessions/new

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
```

**Does anyone know why the WebServer doesn't become operational?**

> Wrapper Manager: JVM #1 Running a 64-bit JVM. Wrapper Manager:
>   Registering shutdown hook Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper Load native
>   library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries
>   do not exist. Loading native library failed:
>   wrapper-windows-x86-64.dll  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   wrapper-windows-x86-64 in java.library.path Loaded native library:
>   wrapper.dll Calling native initialization method. Initializing
>   WrapperManager native library. Java Executable:
>   C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe Windows version: 6.1.7601
>   Java Version   : 1.8.0_91-b15 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Java
>   VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation
>
> Control event monitor thread started. Startup runner thread started.
>   WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@38af3868,
>   args[]) called by thread: main Communications runner thread started.
>   Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection Opened Socket from 31000
>   to 32000 Send a packet KEY : fnnZL60VqJstVqYQ
>   handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31000])
>   Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1 Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from
>   Wrapper is 1 Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 200 PingTimeout from
>   Wrapper is 200000 Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
>   Received a packet START : start calling WrapperListener.start()
>   Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
>   WrapperListener.start runner thread started. WrapperSimpleApp:
>   start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
>   WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
>   2016.07.28 13:48:38 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.6\temp
>   2016.07.28 13:48:38 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.6\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\management-agent.jar -cp
>   ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer
>   D:\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.6\temp\sq-process6103713257744114100properties
>   Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000 Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
>   WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false,
>   exitCode=null WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped. returned
>   from WrapperListener.start() Send a packet STARTED :  Startup runner
>   thread stopped. Received a packet PING : ping Send a packet PING : ok
>   2016.07.28 13:48:41 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
>   2016.07.28 13:48:41 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
>   2016.07.28 13:48:42 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469706518062] version[1.7.5], pid[3788],
>   build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
>   2016.07.28 13:48:42 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469706518062] initializing ...
>   2016.07.28 13:48:42 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1469706518062] loaded [], sites []
>   2016.07.28 13:48:43 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1469706518062] using [1] data paths, mounts [[Data (D:)]], net
>   usable_space [29.5gb], net total_space [249.9gb], types [NTFS]
>   Received a packet PING : ping Send a packet PING : ok
>   2016.07.28 13:48:46 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
>   2016.07.28 13:48:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469706518062] initialized
>   2016.07.28 13:48:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469706518062] starting ...
>   2016.07.28 13:48:47 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1469706518062] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address
>   {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
>   2016.07.28 13:48:47 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1469706518062] sonarqube/NDLYofdsQU6dCANZLN0p9w Received a packet PING : ping Send a
>   packet PING : ok
>   2016.07.28 13:48:50 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1469706518062] new_master
>   [sonar-1469706518062][NDLYofdsQU6dCANZLN0p9w][DEERLA7LRUD10A][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1469706518062},
>   reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
>   2016.07.28 13:48:50 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469706518062] started
>   2016.07.28 13:48:50 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1469706518062] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
>   2016.07.28 13:48:51 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
>   2016.07.28 13:48:51 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.6\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\management-agent.jar -cp
>   ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;D:\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.6\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar
>   org.sonar.server.app.WebServer
>   D:\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.6\temp\sq-process200048299209178132properties
>   Received a packet PING : ping Send a packet PING : ok
>   2016.07.28 13:48:55 TRACE web[o.s.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo from INIT to STARTING => true
>   2016.07.28 13:48:55 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
>   2016.07.28 13:48:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: D:\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.6\web
>   2016.07.28 13:48:56 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-xxx.xxx.x.xxx-xxxx"]
>   2016.07.28 13:48:56 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Received a packet PING : ping
>   Send a packet PING : ok
>   2016.07.28 13:48:57 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-xxx.xxx.x.xxx-xxxx"]
>   2016.07.28 13:48:57 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
>   2016.07.28 13:48:57 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
>   2016.07.28 13:48:57 TRACE web[o.s.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo from STARTING to STARTED => true
>   2016.07.28 13:48:58 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
>   2016.07.28 13:48:58 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[ce]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.6\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\management-agent.jar -cp
>   ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;./lib/ce/*;D:\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.6\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar
>   org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer
>   D:\SonarQube\sonarqube-5.6\temp\sq-process346661778793077863properties
>   2016.07.28 13:48:59 TRACE ce[o.s.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo from INIT to STARTING => true
>   2016.07.28 13:48:59 INFO  ce[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting ce
>   2016.07.28 13:48:59 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Waiting for Web Server to be operational...
>   2016.07.28 13:49:00 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer... Received a packet PING : ping Send a packet
>   PING : ok
>   2016.07.28 13:49:02 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer... Received a packet PING : ping Send a packet
>   PING : ok

Answer (score 0):

There should be a line on the log like this

```
2017.01.08 23:12:11 WARN  web[o.s.s.p.DatabaseServerCompatibility] Database must be upgraded. Please backup database and browse /setup
```

The server is waiting the user to go to the /setup page to upgrade the DB before continue.

Answer (score 0):

As per below log line

```
WARN  web[o.s.s.p.DatabaseServerCompatibility] Database must be upgraded. Please backup database and browse /setup
```

Go to `http://<sonar-host>:9000/<context path>/setup`

and click on Migrate button.

After successful migration, your server will ready to use.